# Why did Java not support generics from v1.0?

Tags: java, generics, jvm

This is not a question about how generics work in Java, about pre/post Java 5 generic support differences, type erasure, etc... there are plenty of questions in SO and general documentation in the Internet with regard to these topics. This is question is more about Java language *archaeology* if you want, as I would like to know the specific reason why full generics support was not included in Java from v1.0 and we had to wait until Java 5 for this to be supported:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>()
```

while from v1.0 we could write this:

```
String[] myArray = new String[]{"some", "random", "strings"}
```

So unless I am missing something obvious here, I can't see why the same compile-time type-safety capabilities that arrays had could not be extended to any other container (collections or otherwise) which would have saved us all a lot of pain in the years to come.

Was it a deliberate design decision? if so, on what grounds?

Comment: every new version of every new language comes with new features, and generic support in java 5 was one of them. you cannot ask for every feature that why it was not in previous version.

Comment: This question can only be properly answered by the designers of the language. One must note that even in C++, after which Java was modeled, generics were a young feature at the time (introduced in the 1990s). Also note that when you design a new language, you have to prioritize, otherwise you'll never get a commercial version going (see Perl 6...).

Comment: @afzalex I don't understand your comment, and surely I don't understand the downvotes. I am not asking for every feature in the world to be included in v1.0, and I am not sure where do you infer that from. My question is about the reason for what it looks to me like a design decision to support a specific feature for some parts of the language and not others

Comment: In v1.0, there weren't even collections. All we had was Vector and Hashtable. Nobody knew what Java would become. It was an attempt at making a portable, simple, blue-collar, OO, GC-based language used for applets in Netscape Navigator. Java grew, got more usages, bigger programs, more complex use-cases, and it thus got new features, step by step. Generics are a very complex matter, and (AFAIK) the only generic example that existed at that time was the STL, which was even more complex. Java wanted to be simple.

Comment: i haven't downvoted you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Was it a deliberate design decision? if so, on what grounds?

The way I heard it<sup>1</sup>, the decision was a pragmatic one.  While the Java team wanted to refine the language further before Java 1.0 was released, there was a "business need" to release Java in the state that is was.  It was perceived (at the time) that there was a short window of opportunity to get a new language in front of developers.  It was thought that if they had delayed, the need for a new language could have been filled by another language / company.

---

<sup>1 - I can't remember who I heard this from, but this is consistent with some of the design anomalies you see in Java even today; e.g. inconsistently names methods, classes that should be interfaces, the strange System.in/out/err statics, and so on.</sup>

Comment: This reason makes sense to me, and while I was hoping for some source to back the answer, I appreciate how hard it is to get reliable sources for a design process that happened more than 20 years ago (also, because I searched for it), so I accepted it.

Answer (score -1):

Product developments usually have life cycles. Feature implementation of a product costs time for research, design, implementation and maintenance. Day by day, year by year product becomes boosted with new features. We cannot ask why a later feature is absent in the earlier release. Its a our common sense which can give the answer for the question like,

#### Why airplane was not invented in stone age?

Comment: No, it is not common sense. And that parallelism is totally inadequate. My question was nothing at all like that but rather, given the option to include or not a certain feature, a design decision is made to not to include it. What were the reasons for that decision? I'm not questioning the decision in itself,  I am not taking for granted the difficulty of generics, I am assuming generics were known back then (unlike the airplane in stone age) even if rarely used in programming languages and wanted to understand better the ground behind the decision. That's all. Why is that wrong?